# Is it possible to use a Postgres Interval data type with Marshmallow schema serialization?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

SqlAlchemy supports [Interval data types](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html) like this:

```
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = "samples"
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    time_interval = Column(Interval(), nullable=True)
```

Is it possible to serialize an interval column type using Marshmallow schemas? I was hoping for something like the following:

```
class SampleSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    time_interval = fields.Interval(allow_none=True)  # not supported
```

...but the **interval** data type is not supported by Marshmallow. The [Marshmallow API documentation](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html) mentions other raw data types and strings, but so far I haven't been able to get this to work.

```
TypeError: Object of type 'timedelta' is not JSON serializable
```

Thank you for any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't provide any validation, I was able to get the schema to work using string:

```
class SampleSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int()
    time_interval = fields.String(allow_none=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TimeDelta` class of Marshmallow Fields as stated in [documentation](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow/blob/dev/src/marshmallow/fields.py#L1441).

You can serialize to `datetime.timedelta` and deseriliaze with `Integer`(default as seconds).